# (Virtual Machine) KVM/QEMU Distributed Resources

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, virtualization, linux-kvm, hosting

How do large VM hosting establishments offer Terabytes of RAM?

Do they just use really large SWAP files? (over a Network FS of some type)?

Or is it that they really have hosts/machines/computers with terabytes of RAM?

For instance, say I had two host computers both with 4gb of RAM and I wanted to a QEMU/KVM VM with, say, 6gb of RAM, how would I do this? (or is it possible)?

Answer (score 1):

Most use clustering like VMware HA or Openstack. Others just buy machines that have TBs of RAM (like IBM S/390). You can probably make a two machine cluster with yours and do it but your network link will be a bad bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a hosting provider offer anywhere close to a terabyte of RAM. They really do have machines with this much capacity however. If you had unlimited money (or a enterprise budget) you could buy a server motherboard with 32 DIMM slots, put a 32GB stick in each slot (which will cost you at least $1,000 per stick) and you would have accomplished a single **terabyte**.

There isn't a way to over-allocate like you want and actually make it work properly. You could possibly trick the VM into thinking it has 6 GB of RAM, but once you reach the limit of what you actually have, it's going to crash. You could use something like [zram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram) to fit more memory into your physical RAM but I highly doubt you would get 6 GB into 4 GB.